# Why am I unable to show the precision of a float value using quantiphy and engfmt?

Tags: python

I'm working on an engineering calculator in python and I found some packages that can convert a float value to engineering notation. First I installed `engfmt`:

Code:

```
from engfmt import to_eng_fmt

num = -327.2051
num = to_eng_fmt(num, prec=4)
print(num)
```

Output:

```
-327.21
```

The second package that I installed is `quantiphy` because it is a new release and serves the same purpose as the `engfmt` :

Code:

```
from quantiphy import Quantity

num = -327.2051
num = Quantity(num).fixed(prec=4)
print(num)
```

Output:

```
-327.21
```

What I want is to show the precision decimal value upto 4 places. like this -327.2051

Version:

- Python == 3.7.9
- quantiphy == 2.12.0
- engfmt == 0.2.0 (I cant install the version 1.1.0 because it gives me an error. This version only works for me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases the keyword argument `prec=` *doesn't specify the number of digits* ***after*** *the decimal point*. It determines the precision of the **whole** number, i.e. the number of **all digits**.

By convention the number of all digits is a specified precision *plus 1,* i.e. your precision `prec=4` gives a *5-digit* result.

Increase your precision to `prec=6` (in your case).